# DownloadProgressChanged get called only after file has been downloaded

Tags: c#

Im trying to use the progress bar to track my download, the only problem the progress value changes only after the file is downloaded to the computer and not during its download.

Here is my code, any help will be appreciated.

```
public void DownloadZaq()
    {

        using (WebClient zaq = new WebClient())
        {
            zaq.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Zaq_DownloadProgressChanged);
            zaq.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Zaq_DownloadFileCompleted);
            zaq.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(http://example.com), @"c:\to\111.jpg");
        }
    }


    public void Zaq_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("download completed");
    }

    public void Zaq_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Comment: Code works for me as posted.  How big is the file?  If it's small, it probably completes it too fast.  Your example uri looks funky.

Comment: I can only imagine that you've changed seem details to shield the guilty parties - but it's difficult to see how `"url" + Filename + ".zaq"` could ever yield a valid URL. If you're going to use placeholders, please use `http://example.com` (or other TLDs)

Comment: URL is valid, the file is downloading, the problem is only with the progress bar, thanks for the advice ill change it to http://example.com

Comment: i have tried it with a few files from 1 MB to 150MB and i have the same problem in all.

Comment: Like I said, this code works.  Open a new project and copy this code there and try it again.  You might have something interfering with it on your current setup.

Comment: very strange, i did open a new project, same as before, i get the file downloaded to my computer, but nothing on the progress bar until file is down.

Comment: Maybe try a different download location from a different server entirely.

Comment: Only works the very first time you download, next time you get the entire content in one whack. Unless the http header contains "Cache-Control: no-cache" http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that DownloadFileAsync is blocking the main thread somehow while checking the DNS. This is what I would try

```
WebClient zaq;
public void DownloadZaq()
{
  zaq = new WebClient();
  zaq.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Zaq_DownloadProgressChanged);
  zaq.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Zaq_DownloadFileCompleted);
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => // Workaround to allow Async call
  {
    try
    {
      zaq.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(http://example.com), @"c:\to\111.jpg");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      zag.Dispose();
    }
  });
}

public void Zaq_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("download completed");
  zag.Dispose();
}

public void Zaq_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it wouldn't work, the problem is not with the file begin downloaded the problem is with the progress bar wont react only after the file is completely downloaded